# with select value in one column:SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

this is my code

```
url = "E:\dataset\state_dataset\drug.csv"
dataframe =  read_csv(url)
df=dataframe.loc[:,['Product Name','Number of Prescriptions','Total Amount Reimbursed','Medicaid Amount Reimbursed']]
df[(df.Number of Prescriptions >= 100)]
```

and I faced the error

File "", line 10
    df[(df.Number of Prescriptions >= 100)]
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

please how can I fixed this error

Comment: `df.Number of Prescriptions` is not a valid python. Have you meant `df["Number of Prescriptions"]`? btw, I doubt you use 2 python versions at once.

Comment: thank you sir for your cooperation. I'm using Anaconda and my python version is 3.6.3. I'm a beginner in python how can I reach to specific value in one column in the data set by using pandas